# Calling .SaveAs Crashes Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have created an `xlam` (Excel 2007 Add-In) file to handle manipulation of various files. I am trying to write a procedure in that `xlam` file that removes some worksheets from an opened `xlsm` file, and saves it as an `xlsx` (i.e. without macros).

So far the only thing I can do reliably is to crash Excel whenever I reach the `.SaveAs` call. The crash comes as a Windows Dialog stating:

> Microsoft Office Excel has stopped working, Windows can try to recover your information and restart the program. [Restart the program] [Debug the Program]

In the folder that I am saving to, after every crash I am left with a temp file (ex. filename: *7A275000* with size: 0) in the folder it tried to save to.

For posterity here some things I have tried, and all have resulted in the same crash:

- Hard coded filename value ("C:\Users\myUserName\Desktop\temp.xlsx")
- Prompted filename from User (shown in code below)
- filename without path ("temp.xlsx")
- filename without extension ("C:\Users\myUserName\Desktop\temp")
- filename as existing filename without extension
- filename as existing filename with .xlsx extension
- instead of using `wb.SaveAs`, I used `wb.Activate` followed by `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs`
- I have tried `FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook` and `FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal`
- Saved to several different directories of varying length
- Added an Error trapping statement around the `.SaveAs` call (it does not trap any errors, and crashes Excel just the same)

The last weird bit is when I try to do a manual Save-As on the file (i.e. navigating to the Save-As menu myself) after the `ws.delete` calls, Excel crashes the same way. If I manually delete the Worksheets myself, then do a manual Save-As, it saves just fine.

---

Here is the offending code:

```
Public Sub ConvertToStagingFile(ByRef wb As Workbook)
    Dim reWS As Object, reFILE As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set reWS = CreateObject("VBScript.regexp")
    reWS.IgnoreCase = True: reWS.Global = False: reWS.MultiLine = False

    Set reFILE = CreateObject("VBScript.regexp")
    reFILE.IgnoreCase = True: reFILE.Global = False: reFILE.MultiLine = False

    reWS.Pattern = "^(home|location settings|date reference|[\w\s]{1,8} (rating|inquire) data|pkl data - \w{1,8}|verbs - \w{1,8})"
    reFILE.Pattern = "\.xlsm$"

    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If (ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden) Or (ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden) Then
            ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        End If

        Select Case True
            Case reWS.test(ws.name)
                '// Do Nothing
            Case Else
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                ws.Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End Select
    Next ws

    ActiveWindow.TabRatio = 0.75

    If (reFILE.test(Cached.getAdhocReportFull)) Then
        Dim newName As Variant

        newName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(reFILE.Replace(Cached.getAdhocReportFull, ""), "*.xlsx")
        If newName = False Then Exit Sub

        wb.Activate

        Application.EnableEvents = False
        '// CODE RELIABLY CRASHES HERE
        wb.SaveAs _
            FileName:=newName, _
            FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, _
            CreateBackup:=False

        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If
End Sub
```

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the size of excel huge????

Comment: Yes... it is large-ish for an excel file. It can be 2-4mb in size. What considerations need to be made for large file saves?

Comment: Try to reduce the size, if range (vlookup, index) have been used try reducing the size, in named formula - reduce the range...or else your file might have corrupted try creating a new version and give a try...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm not sure it applies here. I am already reducing the filesize by deleting approximately half of the Worksheets in the document. The `.SaveAs` attempts to save without  vba as well which reduces the overall file size.

Answer (score 0):

I had what seems like exactly the same issue:

- Excel 2013
- Macro to delete worksheet in xlsm file
- Subsequent calls to .Save, or manually saving file crashes Excel (same dialog as Hari)
- The issue only appeared for us when we updated from .xls to the 'new' office file format
- For info, our files are not that large (only 300kB)

As our intention is to replace the sheet the following works for us: rename old worksheet, create new worksheet (same name as old worksheet), delete the old worksheet. Seems to work for us. Why does it work? No idea.